# Group Values in Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, range

I want to group the values and put them in one range.
Eg:
A column VALUE has values in the range of 1 to 1000. The number of rows is 1L+.
I want a new column where the values are grouped in the range of <200, 200-400, 400-600, 600-800, 800+
How to move ahead?[What is expected. See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37ZXd.png)

Comment: Hi! Have you done some research beforehand? Maybe add some starter code and show what you want? It usually helps if you have a bit of toy data. Would you share a bit of what you've tried? Also, it's a little bit hard to understand exactly what this question is about, so maybe try to clarify a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can specify bins and then use [pd.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = [0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000]
labels = ['{}-{}'.format(i, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 

df['range_column'] = pd.cut(df['existing_column'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```